# Is it OK to nest Formik forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I need to have a form with multiple radio groups. The form is handled by Formik. Inside each radio group I want to give user a possibility to add an element using another form. It's wrapped in Formik too because I want to have independent validation. It might look something like this:

[image]

The child Formik doesn't have to know anything about the parent Formik and vise versa.

Question: Is it OK to nest two (or even more) Formiks like this? Can it bring some unexpected side effects? If this is a bad practice please explain why and suggest a better structure of components.

I know that nesting form elements is not valid HTML, but that's not an issue here because I don't render it in inner Formik.

Example [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-formiks-h0b14r). App.jsx has Formik and NewCustomerForm.jsx has Formik too.

The code in question might look something like this:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{ customer: '' }}
  onSubmit={submitForm}
  validate={validate}
>
  <Form>
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="111" />
    <input type="radio" name="customer" value="222" />

    <Formik
      initialValues={{ address: { country: '', city: '' } }}
      onSubmit={submitAddress}
      validate={validateAddress}
    >
      {({ handleSubmit }) => (
        <>
          <input name="address.country" />
          <input name="address.city" />
          <button onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Save</button>
        </>
      )}
    </Formik>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Comment: Almost feels like the ACTUAL code might be better on the Code Review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The OP hasn't written the code yet, this question would definitely be rejected quickly on code review. The OP seems to be asking us to write the code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw how has the OP not written any code when they added a CodeSandBox link? Unless the code is incomplete

Comment: @pacmaninbw maybe read the question before commenting? I'm not asking for any code. I'm asking a conceptual question. And yes, I wrote the code and added the link just in case.